# insert multiple rows in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner php code and I am trying to update multiple rows of data with this update loop. It will only update the database with the last entry.

```
$size = count($_POST['wkmove_id']);
$i=0;
while( $i < $size ) {
   // define each variable
   $rps = $_POST['sessrps'][$i];
   $wgt = $_POST['sesswgt'][$i];
   $mv = $_POST['wkmove_id'][$i];

   echo " cat=$cat subcat=$subcat mv= $mv wgt=$wgt rps=$rps<br>";

   $sql = "INSERT INTO wkout_sess 
                 (wkprog_id, wkname_id, wkmove_id, sesswgt, sessrps)
                  VALUES ('$cat','$subcat','$mv','$wgt','$rps')";
   ++$i; 
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{

   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "1 record added";
```

This output will show

```
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 1 wgt=45 rps=4
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 2 wgt=15 rps=4
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 3 wgt=10 rps=2
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 4 wgt=12 rps=1
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 5 wgt=5 rps=54
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 6 wgt=1 rps=6
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 7 wgt=2 rps=6
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 8 wgt=1 rps=6
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 9 wgt=1 rps=2
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 10 wgt=6 rps=1
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 11 wgt=4 rps=69
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 12 wgt=8 rps=6
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 13 wgt=4 rps=8
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 14 wgt=9 rps=4
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 15 wgt=1 rps=2
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 16 wgt=3 rps=6
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 17 wgt=5 rps=4
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 18 wgt=8 rps=7
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 19 wgt=4 rps=6
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 20 wgt=9 rps=7
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 21 wgt=8 rps=9
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 22 wgt=4 rps=1
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 23 wgt=4 rps=1
cat=1 subcat=1 mv= 24 wgt=9 rps=7

1 record added
```

How do I get it to add all previous 23 entries as well?

Comment: Just perform your queries in a loop. Or, ebtter yet, build one query in the loop and execute after the loop is completed.

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: ^ Listen to tadman, and perfomance wise, remember: running `INSERT INTO TABLE table (column1,column2) VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8);` is a lot faster then running those queries separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the query after the while loop. You want to run it IN the while loop. Also, please note that you are using deprecated mysql_* functions and should move to PDO or MySQLi.

The sql string `$sql` is only being run once, and that is for it's last value in the loop.

Comment: so how do I do it In the while loop rather than after? do I need a for loop?

Comment: @dac086 I am saying you need to run this code `mysql_query($sql,$con)` in your while loop. Right now it is only being executed ONCE, AFTER your while loop has run. If that still does not make sense I am afraid you are going to have to learn the basics of flow of control before anyone can further help you on this problem.